# Finding Index of a Node in a Huffman Tree

Tags: java, tree, huffman-code

Assume we have a tree of nodes (Huffman-tree) that hold string values in them. How would I go about traversing the tree and spitting out an index of a specific node if I had a tree like this? The numbers I drew inside the circles would be the **index** I want (especially 12 or 13).[image: BST]

Note: Due to miscommunication, I will repeat: the #'s I wrote inside the circles are **not** the values that the nodes hold. They are the **index** of that node. My problem was that I couldn't find the index, since the trees are structured weirdly - not a classic BST tree, and the values inside aren't numerical.

**Edit:** I redrew the image to make my question more clear.
Either way, I figured it out. I'll write up the answer after my finals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tree you are showing is not a binary search tree. The central property of a binary search tree that allows it to be searched efficiently is that the left descendants of a node are smaller, and the right descendants bigger than the node itself (in terms of the index value).

If you have a proper binary search tree, you can find a node with given index by comparing with nodes and following the corresponding branch, starting with the root.

Comment: Quoting my question: "Assume we have a tree of nodes that hold string values in them" and "The numbers I drew inside the circles would be the index I want (especially 12 or 13)."

Comment: I'm working on an assignment that is dealing with more of a Huffman Tree like structure